# CLion C++ header files not found after macOS is updated to Catalina

Tags: c++, iostream, clion

I am using CLion for my C++ projects. After I updated my macOS to Catalina, my C++ files cannot find `<iostream>`,  etc anymore. I have read similar issues online but I couldn't find where to add the build path or find the header file path. If anyone can help me with this problem, thank you in advance.

Comment: If this is a cmake project then go to the Cmake tab and refresh the cache.

Answer (score 2):

Open CMake tab at the bottom
Click CMake Settings:
[CMake Setttings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCrZA.png)

[Inside CMake Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNAnG.png)

Press "Manage Toolchains"

Wait until CLion populates all the fields and press OK

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue after a Fedora Linux OS upgrade.

Tools -> CMake -> "Reload CMake Project" resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Happened the same way to me but I saw the other answer first, tried that, and it did indeed fill in the missing details of the compiler installation -- but the error persisted until I did an "Invalidate caches and restart", so not sure if these were both key or just the latter.