# CLion header files <vector>, <iostream> not known to be header unit?

Tags: c++, c++20, clion

I just installed Clion and am trying to write a short program in C++. However, when I try to `import <iostream>` or `import <vector>` I get

```
Header file <iostream> (aka '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/iostream') cannot be imported because it is not known to be a header unit
```

The project is in C++ 20, in my CMakeLists.txt I did  `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)`

I tried following the instructions here [CLion C++ header files not found after macOS is updated to Catalina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419023/clion-c-header-files-not-found-after-macos-is-updated-to-catalina) but it didn't resolve my issue

Comment: You should probably clarify if this an an ide reported error, a build system error or a compiler reported error.

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] that shows the code that fails?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant `#include <iostream>`.

Header units (with `import`) are the new thing in C++20 and they are not yet fully supported by tools.